# Alternative to Windows and cloud for Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm starting to learn Ruby on Rails and after a week I still cannot get the installation right.  I've since moved to a cloud bases system, but it is extremely slow and rather a waste of time.

I do have a website and saw there's Ruby on Rails.  Is it perhaps possible to set it up in a domain or sub domain and start and start learning/programming that way?

Any other alternatives is also welcome.  I do now own a mac or Ubuntu, which makes it a little difficult.

Looking forward to your responses.  In the meantime I'm installing/uninstalling and trying to see if I can somehow make it work on Windows.

Comment: Doing RoR development on Windows is a pain. I would suggest just uninstalling Windows and going for some Linux distribution if you are serious about learning RoR. Linux is free software so the only thing holding you back from having it on your computer is your self.

Comment: What are in the way of getting the installation right ?

Comment: http://railsinstaller.org/en will get you going with Ruby very easily.

Comment: Thank you for that.  I am looking at at the two links you send, me.  Really appreciate it.  Much as I want to jump right into Rails and start working on my idea, I realize maybe I should spend some time on Ruby and while I'm at it, learn stuff like MySQL which is currently giving my so much issues with the installation of Rails.  Also see Node JS is sort of an "alternative" which allows you to do much the same as with Rails.  If all else fails I might learn Node JS in the meantime.

Answer (score -1):

Doing RoR development on Windows is a pain. I would suggest just uninstalling Windows and going for some Linux distribution if you are serious about learning RoR. Linux is free software so the only thing holding you back from having it on your computer is your self.

Developing with Ruby on Rails is say'd to be really easy for beginners but I would disagree with it. Developing on this framework requires you to actually understand the whole stack. The server, backend, client, database and ofcourse a new weird language called `Ruby`. Now most of this stuff is learnable and doable on every OS. But once you start messing with more advanced databases and servers, you will need some GNU utils from Linux.

For instance if you have made your first deployment to some external server, you will often need to know what is going on in there. The only way to do this is usually by going in that server with SSH and reading the logs. But doing that is difficult without a nice GUI. So now you have to learn some stuff like the `tail` and `grep` commands and Linux piping to find your info easily.

Also if the computer you use is not completely yours and you cannot do it on it, then try installing a virtual machine software like [Virtual box](https://www.virtualbox.org/).

With that you can install Ruby on a Linux that sits on your VM and use it like that. It will still be a bit slower but if your computer has decent hardware in it, you will still be happy with it.

Here is a guide on how you could do it: [Guide for VM development](https://gorails.com/guides/using-vagrant-for-rails-development)

Comment: while I agree with you in principle, learning an entire new OS just to try out a programming language isn't feasible. Tools like Rails Installer (http://railsinstaller.org/en) work just fine at getting spun up with Ruby and Rails on a Windows environment.

Comment: But knowing from my own experience they will scare away the brave developer that is trying it once they start getting near the deployment phase. Then they will suddenly see that getting for instance a pg gem working on windows is pretty much a rocket science.